# Visualize count of logs on AWS CloudWatch by dashboard

Tags: amazon-cloudwatch

I have a web application which emits lines of json-formatted logs to stdout.

I want to...
1. save the logs on AWS CloudWatch
2. visualize the timeseries of the number of logs which match a custom condition

Is there any solution that summerizes (i.e. count) the custom logs on AWS CloudWatch dashboard?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) To save the logs on cloudwatch you can install the [cloudwatch logs agent](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/logs/AgentReference.html) on your EC2 instance (if that is what you are serving your app from). You will need to configure which logs are sent in `/etc/awslogs/awslogs.conf` (and 
 `/etc/awslogs/awscli.conf` for the region setting).

2) For visualising the logs you can do a fair amount with Cloudwatch Logs Insights, which uses its own [query language](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/logs/AnalyzingLogData.html) to analyse your logs from any given group

Comment: Thanks a lot! I followed your suggestion, and got a good visualization result!